# Remote desktop to a VM that is on ESXi v4.0

Tags: vmware-esxi, remote, desktop

I can't seem to get a remote session started from my pc to a Windows 2003 server vm that is residing on a VMware ESXi server. I can connect with the VMware client software and I can remote out of the Windows server to another server but not into the server.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

Have you enabled Remote Desktop on the VM itself?

Start+PauseBreak > Remote > Check 'Allow users to remotely connect'

Answer (score 2):

In general I always check:

- Will the firewall allow my connection?
- Is remote desktop allowed?
- Is remote desktop configured to allow requesting client's remote desktop version?
- Do I have the network enabled and configured on every dependent device? (This is actually overlooked sometimes..)
- Do the windows license allow more than one concurrent session? If not; is no one else using the host at the moment?

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had to enable the RDP in Terminal Services Configuration and pick the Vmware virtual interface.  I did get a prompt once I went to the adpaters tab that the the interfacoe had changed and I needed to select one.

Answer (score 0):

I get this problem sometimes after windows updates.On Wednesday I will be able to RDP to the server, Thursday I won't.

I found that you have to go to "terminal services configuration\connections", right-click "rdp", then click on the "adapter" tab, switching it from "all network adapters" to a specified one, or vice versa works for me. You will have to reboot the server for the change to take place, sadly.